# Why do I have so many errors from the BaseGameUtils library?

Tags: java, android

I am following this link

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

With trying to add leaderboards to an android app but after I follow step 1 and it is added it throws up over 100 errors and a `Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies`error, that I understand why.

I have added the google play library no problem and gotten adverts to work by following Google's documentation but the leaderboard documentation seems to be sending me all over the place and not helping at all.

Could someone please shed some light on this, thanks!

Comment: That JAR Mismatch is a -really- common error with the support libraries. Just make sure both of the projects are pointing to the same android-support-v4.jar (or whichever version you're using) and then clean the project. I run into that one every single time I set up a new dev machine.

Comment: You're probably including same JAR twice with different versions: the one one in Android library and the one in your own project.

Comment: I understand the mismatch error but its the fact that the imported files themselves are causing 125 errors thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok because I am still new to Android and Eclipse I had added the reference to the BaseGameUtils in the properties for the project but you have to add the Google play services as a reference for the BaseGameUtils by right clicking and selecting properties then add it as you did for the main project.